# Когда инфинитив не  является частью сказуемого?

Tags: синтаксис

Какую роль в предложении играет инфинитив в таких случаях и почему?

Люблю учиться. Поеду учиться. Хочу учиться.

Answer (score 5):

***Поеду С КАКОЙ ЦЕЛЬЮ? ЗАЧЕМ? учиться***. Учиться здесь зависимое слово, обстоятельство.

Не любое сочетание спрягаемого глагола с инфинитивом является составным глагольным сказуемым! Для того чтобы такое сочетание было составным глагольным сказуемым, должно быть выполнено два условия:

**Вспомогательный глагол должен быть лексически неполнозначным**, то есть его одного (без инфинитива) недостаточно, чтобы понять, о чем идёт речь в предложении.

Cр.: я начал – что делать?; я хочу – что делать?.
Если в сочетании «глагол + инфинитив» глагол знаменательный, то он один является простым глагольным сказуемым, а инфинитив – второстепенный член предложения.

Ср.: ***Она присела (с какой целью?) отдохнуть***.

**Действие инфинитива должно относиться к подлежащему** (это субъектный инфинитив). Если действие инфинитива относится к другому члену предложения (объектный инфинитив), то инфинитив не входит в состав сказуемого, а является второстепенным членом.

Ср.:
1. Я хочу петь. Хочу петь – составное глагольное сказуемое (хочу – я, петь буду – я).
2. ***Я просил её спеть***. Просил – простое глагольное сказуемое, ***спеть – дополнение*** (**просил – я, петь будет – она**).[Посмотрите здесь](http://www.licey.net/russian/syntax/r1_1_4)

Comment: Все так. Но на самом деле несколько запутанно. (Не у Вас. Вообще в теории). Значит, в сочетании люблю читать - люблю вспомогательный глагол,  а в сочетании люблю чтение  - уже полнозначный? Никто не указывает в СИС слова типа люблю как связки.

Comment: Совершенно с Вами согласна.

Answer (score 1):

Если инфинитив отвечает не только на глагольный вопрос, то он будет второстепенным членом предложения:Люблю (кого? что?) учиться (учебу). Поеду (с какой целью?) учиться. Хочу (чего?) учиться.

Comment: Люблю учиться, хочу учиться - инфинитив входит в сказуемое.

Answer (score 1):

*Я хожу в библиотеку читать.*
Здесь    инфинитив является обстоятельством.
*Хочу научиться  читать.*
Здесь *читать* дополнение (хочу научиться **чему?**).
Мне видится так.

Answer (score 0):

Почему-то никто из уважаемых дискутантов не упомянул наиболее  простой способ отличить вспомогательный глагол при инфинитиве от простого глагольного сказумого, когда инфинитив является каким-то второстепенным членом предложения. Кажется, Розенталь называл такие глаголы ( в СГС) глаголами со стертым лексическим значением: люблю читать, начну читать, стану читать, хочу читать... Вот они и являются частью составного сказуемого. А другие глаголы, со значением конкретного действия, выступают в роли простых глагольных, при которых инфинитив может быть второстепенным членом, обычно обстоятельством или дополнением.

Comment: Ну, почему никто не сказал?  Об этом есть в самом вопросе. Только там  глаголы со стёртым лексическим значением  названы лексически неполнозначными.

Comment: Ой, сорри. Это не в вопросе, а в комментарии EkaterinaKas...